# Update my table, Tenterexit, using a select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table with 1628 rows. It contains the daily enter/exit register. I would like to mark the first enter/person/day. I try to update my table with the following query but it does not work. Where is my fault?

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Tenterexit]
SET 
    [mark] =1
where exists
    (SELECT MIN( [id] )
    ,[name]
    ,[day]     
    FROM [dbo].[Tenterexit] WHERE [INF]=0 GROUP BY [Name]  ,[day])
```

The `[inf]=0` means the passage is enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `update -> from` clause.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Tenterexit]
SET 
    [mark] =1
FROM
    (SELECT MIN([id]) id         
        FROM [dbo].[Tenterexit] WHERE [INF]=0 GROUP BY [Name],[day]) t2
WHERE t2.id = [Tenterexit].id
```

Comment: I was amazed to find that worked - I would personally suggest that Zaynul's answer is easier to follow for a beginner and clearer in general.

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
UPDATE t  
   SET 
   [mark] =1
from [dbo].[Tenterexit] t
   where t.id in ( select MIN([id])

   FROM [dbo].[Tenterexit] t1 WHERE [INF]=0 GROUP BY [Name]  ,[day]
   )
```